# dotnetbrowser does not work properly after setting socks5

Tags: winforms, dotnetbrowser

After setting socks5 proxy IP, dotnetbrowser can't access it, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error appears, does dotnetbrowser support socks5, how to set it correctly if it does?

I set it up this way, but it didn't work

```
engine.Profiles.Default.Network.AuthenticateHandler = new Handler<AuthenticateParameters, AuthenticateResponse>(p =>
            {
                if (p.IsProxy)
                {
                    return AuthenticateResponse.Continue("usernamne", "password");
                }
                else
                {
                    return AuthenticateResponse.Cancel();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because DotNetBrowser is based on Chromium which doesn't support SOCKS5 with authentication.

There is a 10 y.o. issue in Chromium's bug tracker that you can star: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256785